# sitefinity TypeError: kendo.syncReady is not a function

Tags: sitefinity

Within my sitefinity project I am using `Kendo.Mvc.UI` controls like @Html.Kendo().TextBox() and @(Html.Kendo().Grid in the view. I have also included the files in the view using the @Html.Script. But I am getting this error about the `kendo.syncReady is not a function` am I missing anything else?

```
@Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "top")
@Html.Script(Url.WidgetContent("~/Mvc/Scripts/Kendo/2020.3.1118/kendo.all.min.js"), "top")
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Mvc/Scripts/kendo/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css" />
<link href="~/Mvc/Scripts/Kendo/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Mvc/Scripts/Kendo/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you want to render kendo and jquery to avoid conflicts

https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/RandomSiteControlsMVC/blob/master/RandomSiteControlsMVC/MVC/Views/TabStrip/Kendo.cshtml

You also want to do something like this so it'll always render below jquery

https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/RandomSiteControlsMVC/blob/master/Demo/ResourcePackages/RSC/MVC/Views/Layouts/default.cshtml#L207

It's all about predictability.

Comment: i am a little confused so I need to add something like this @Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "Top") @Html.Script(ScriptRef.KendoWeb, "top") to my view?

Comment: `@Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "head")`
`@Html.Script(ScriptRef.KendoWeb, "head")`


`@Html.Section("jquery")`
`@Html.Section("kendo")`

Comment: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-access-kendo-libraries-that-are-shipped-with-sitefinity

Comment: I don’t see where you Import the dll @using kendo.Mvc.Ui in the top of the view?